# spring data REST webmvc HATEOAS - How to identify target type in a link property?

Tags: json, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I am working on a CRUD application using spring-data-rest-webmvc.

I have a Product entity as below:-

```
{
"version": 0,
"displayName": "Test Product",
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost/services/data/products/123465"
    },
    "fixedParentCategories": {
        "href": "http://localhost/services/data/products/123465/fixedParentCategories"
    }
}
```

When I access the URL for the property "fixedParentCategories" (http://localhost/services/data/products/123465/fixedParentCategories), it returns a 404 (ResourceNotFoundException thrown and translated to 404).

The problem that I have here is that, this 404 response does not help me identify what type of objects go into this collection (fixedParentCategories).

If there is an item present in the collection, I get a response like below:-

```
{
"_embedded": {
    "categories": [
        {
            "version": 0,
            "displayName": "Test category",
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/services/data/categories/54c9963a8c21fbd950b6f1cf"
                },
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

It clearly says that the items are of type "categories".

My question is: Is there any way of identifying the target item type when the collection is empty, so that the client side code can address it properly?